# Plot benchmark experiment results as one plot

Tags: r, plot

I was benchmarking different implementations of an algorithm as part of a project and wanted to visualize this data in R succinctly. I was thinking I could assign different versions to different colors and use x axis of the plot to represent size and y axis to represent time. Please let me know how to plot these results in R. If there is any other way that would look better, I'd be happy to follow as well.

```
Size
8192            2      1     1      1
65536          10      5     4      4
1048576        81      60    63     52
8388608        675     555   572    464
16777216      1334    1124   1171   953
33554432      2780    2348   2438   2014
67108864      5853    5229   4957   4238
134217728     12437   10303  10521  8921
```

|__________
[image]

Comment: something like `library(reshape2); library(ggplot2); d <- melt(mytab,...); ggplot(d,aes(x=Var1,y=value,colour=Var2))+geom_point()+geom_line()+scale_x_log10()+scale_y_log10()`.  Could you please (pretty please) post your data as something other than a screenshot, so it can be cut-and-pasted???

Comment: Or in base R you can do it in a single line: `matplot(mytab[1],mytab[-1],type="o",lty=1,pch=19,log="xy")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just putting @BenBolker's answer down here to close out the question. (If you would like, Ben, feel free to copy/paste this as your own.)

Here's your sample input:

```
mytab <- structure(list(Size = c(8192L, 65536L, 1048576L, 8388608L, 16777216L, 
33554432L, 67108864L, 134217728L), Version1 = c(2L, 10L, 81L, 
675L, 1334L, 2780L, 5853L, 12437L), Version2 = c(1L, 5L, 60L, 
555L, 1124L, 2348L, 5229L, 10303L), Version3 = c(1L, 4L, 63L, 
572L, 1171L, 2438L, 4957L, 10521L), Version4 = c(1L, 4L, 52L, 
464L, 953L, 2014L, 4238L, 8921L)), .Names = c("Size", "Version1", 
"Version2", "Version3", "Version4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

and here's now to make the plot

```
library(reshape2); 
library(ggplot2); 

d <- melt(mytab, "Size"); 

ggplot(d,aes(x=Size,y=value,colour=variable))+
geom_point()+
geom_line()+
scale_x_log10()+scale_y_log10()
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: maybe you can improve how you read in the data using this:

`datatext="..."
mydata <- read.table(text=datatext, col.names=c("size", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"))`, sorry my code looks so crappy in the comment, but you basically read the text string using `read.table(text=..)`. instead of building that long data frame command.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. I'm assuming the data has already been read into R. I just `dput()` the data.frame to make it easy to copy/paste. That's a much better way to share data.frames since it preserves column class properties and you don't have to much about with delimiters and such. It's much nicer to share a `dput()` than force other to re-import the data.